# Using autoprops in eclipse for all files and folders in an svn project

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, mime-types

Pre-commit triggers recently introduced to my institution's svn are proving troublesome.

They require every file to have the property:

- svn:mime-type=text/plain
- svn:eol-style=native

Manually (in eclipse), I can right-click on the Java Project Folder and navigate Team>SetProperty. I then enter the properties listed above one by one ticking apply property recursively to all resources before clicking OK.

I am then able to commit.

This process is arduous and has to be repeated every time a new file is introduced.

As a result, I am keen to implement the use of autoprops within eclipse.

Navigating Window>Preferences>Team>SVN>Properties Configuration, I import the following file:

```
[auth]

[helpers]

[tunnels]

[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.* = svn:mime-type=text/plain;svn:eol-style=native
```

This works great for files. However, the settings are not applied to newly created directories.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Subversion 1.8 or newer client then you can start using the `svn:auto-props` versioned property to set these `svn:mime-type`, `svn:eol-style` and other properties automatically. See the following articles:

- [SVNBook | Inherited Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable) & [SVNBook | Automatic Property Setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto),
- [Subversion 1.8 Release Notes | Inherited Properties](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#iprops).

> This works great for files. However, the settings are not applied to
>   newly created directories.

The value of auto-props section you have is `*.*`. The property applies only to files and directories with the name like `foo.bar`. You can leave just `*` and the property will apply to all newly-added items.